# simplify $\sqrt{(45+4\sqrt{41})^3}-\sqrt{(45-4\sqrt{41})^3}$

Tags: radicals, nested-radicals

simplify $\sqrt{(45+4\sqrt{41})^3}-\sqrt{(45-4\sqrt{41})^3}$.

> 1.$90^{\frac{3}{2}}$
>
> 2.$106\sqrt{41}$
>
> 3.$4\sqrt{41}$
>
> 4.$504$
>
> 5.$508$

**My attempt**:I do like this but I didn't get any of those five.

$\sqrt{(45+4\sqrt{41})^3}-\sqrt{(45-4\sqrt{41})^3}={\sqrt{45+4\sqrt{41}}}^3-\sqrt{45-4\sqrt{41}}^3$

$=(\sqrt{45+4\sqrt{41}}-\sqrt{45-4\sqrt{41}})(45+4\sqrt{41}+45-4\sqrt{41}+(\sqrt{45+4\sqrt{41}})(\sqrt{45-4\sqrt{41}})$

Now I do the nested radicals formula and I get $254\sqrt{41}$ which is none of those where did I mistaked?

Comment: How'd you "do the nested radicals" formulas to get $254\sqrt{41}$? Can't tell you where you went wrong if you dont tell us what you did.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is this the nested radical formula?

$\sqrt{45 \pm 4\sqrt{41}} = a \pm b\sqrt{41}$

$45 \pm 4\sqrt{41} = (a^2 + 41b^2) \pm 2ab\sqrt{41}$

$a^2 + 41b^ = 45; 2ab = 4 \implies a=2;b = 1$

So $\sqrt{45 \pm 4\sqrt{41}} = |2 \pm \sqrt{41}|= \pm 2 + \sqrt{41}$

Plugging that into: $=(\sqrt{45+4\sqrt{41}}-\sqrt{45-4\sqrt{41}})(45+4\sqrt{41}+45-4\sqrt{41}+(\sqrt{45+4\sqrt{41}})(\sqrt{45-4\sqrt{41}}))$

We get $(2+\sqrt{41} - (-2+\sqrt{41}))(90+(2 + \sqrt{41})(-2+\sqrt{41}))=$

$4(90 + (-4 + 41)) = 508$

===

It would have been easier not to do all the expanding:

$(2 + \sqrt{41})^3 - (-2+\sqrt{41})^3=$

$(2^3 + 3*2^2*\sqrt{41}  + 3*2*\sqrt{41}^2+\sqrt{41}^3)- (-2^3 + 3*2^2*\sqrt{41}  - 3*2*\sqrt{41}^2+\sqrt{41}^3)=$

$2(8 + 6*41) = 508$.

Comment: $2-\sqrt{41} < 0$, so this is not correct.

Comment: So?  Why can't $2 - \sqrt{41} < 0$.  No where ever to we take the $\sqrt{\sqrt{41 - 4\sqrt{41}}}$.

Comment: It is, but $\sqrt x \geq 0$.

Comment: And where on earth did we do $\sqrt{2 - \sqrt{41}}$?

Comment: Ok, let me be explicit: $\sqrt{45-4\sqrt{41}} \neq 2-\sqrt{41}$ because $2-\sqrt{41} < 0$.

Comment: The $\sqrt{45-4\sqrt{41}} = \sqrt{41} - 2$ and we get $16 + 12*41 = 508$.  ... oh, bugger.

Comment: Gad, that was a dumb mistake...

Comment: Oh, well, it happens. It is subtle, and I guess the point of the exercise. Anyway, we might as well remove these comments now. (Though, you might want to notify OP of the edit).

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
$$45\pm4\sqrt{41}=(2\pm\sqrt{41})^2.$$

Answer (score 0):

When I see expression where both $\alpha = a+b\sqrt{n}$ and $\beta =a-b\sqrt n$ occur, I immediately calculate $\alpha + \beta = 2a$ and $\alpha\beta = a^2-nb^2$ since they are guaranteed to be integers (more precisely, the minimal polynomial of both of them is $x^2 - (\alpha+\beta)x+\alpha\beta$ which might be helpful in some cases; if you are not familiar with the term, just ignore this remark). So, we have $$x = \sqrt{\alpha^3}-\sqrt{\beta^3}\implies x^2 = \alpha^3 -2\sqrt{(\alpha\beta)^3}+\beta^3\\
\implies x^2 = (\alpha + \beta)(\alpha^2-\alpha\beta+\beta^2)-2\sqrt{(\alpha\beta)^3}\\
\implies x^2 = (\alpha + \beta)((\alpha-\beta)^2+\alpha\beta)-2\sqrt{(\alpha\beta)^3}$$

Now, in your case $\alpha\beta = 1369 = 37^2$, so we have $$x^2 = 90((2\cdot 4\sqrt{41})^2+1369)-2\cdot 37^3 = 258064\implies x= 508$$

Answer (score 0):

Considering all positive values, $45\pm4\sqrt{41}$ can be written as $45\pm4\sqrt{41}=(\sqrt{41}\pm2)^2$, thus, the given expression can be simplified as follows: $$\sqrt{(45+4\sqrt{41})^3}-\sqrt{(45-4\sqrt{41})^3}=\left(\sqrt{45+4\sqrt{41}}\right)^3-\left(\sqrt{45-4\sqrt{41}}\right)^3=\left(\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{41}+2\right)^2}\right)^3-\left(\sqrt{\left(\sqrt{41}-2\right)^2}\right)^3=\left(\sqrt{41}+2\right)^3-\left(\sqrt{41}-2\right)^3$$
Now recall, $a^3-b^3=(a-b)(a^2+ab+b^2)$. Thus, $$\left(\sqrt{41}+2\right)^3-\left(\sqrt{41}-2\right)^3=\left((\sqrt{41}+2)-(\sqrt{41}-2)\right)\left((\sqrt{41}+2)^2+(\sqrt{41}+2)(\sqrt{41}-2)+(\sqrt{41}-2)^2\right)=\left(\sqrt{41}+2-\sqrt{41}+2\right)\left(45+4\sqrt{41}+41-4+45-4\sqrt{41}\right)=4(45+41-4+45)=508$$